# Trouble with pull request

Tags: github, pull-request

I have problem with pull request. I have created a pull request and added collaborator. When collaborator rewiewed my code, i didnt get a comments about code , but have this message

[image]

Also colloborator placed in reviewers with message "Awaiting requested review from ... "

Someone can help me?

Comment: Are you sure the collaborator submitted their review? GitHub let’s you comment on code and then submit the review all at once, often people are confused by this. Regarding the message you’re seeing, they probably manually set themselves as a reviewer.

Comment: Yes, i am sure.

Comment: Sorry, collaborator didn`t submitted review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the collaborator made comments but didn’t actually submit their review. The comments won’t be visible until after they’ve submitted.